# Laravel Sail/Docker Pusher - Soketi

Tags: laravel, docker, websocket, laravel-sail

I running Laravel Sail via Docker and I have been running Soketi container success.
On localhost: it can be listen success
But when I deploy to server, I got an error like this:

```
WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

from [wss://127.0.0.1:6001/app/app-key?protocol=7&client=js&version=8.0.2&flash=false](https://wss://127.0.0.1:6001/app/app-key?protocol=7&client=js&version=8.0.2&flash=false)

These are my config:
In broadcasting.php:

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY', 'app-key'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET', 'app-secret'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID', 'app-id'),
            'options' => [
                'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('PUSHER_PORT', 6001),
                'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'http'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'useTLS' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME') === 'https',
            ],
        ],
```

In bootstrap.js:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER ?? 'mt1',
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST ? import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST : `ws-${import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}.pusher.com`,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 80,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 443,
    forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
    encrypted: true,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
    authorizer: (channel, options) => {
        return {
            authorize: (socketId, callback) => {
                axios.post('/api/broadcasting/auth', {
                    socket_id: socketId,
                    channel_name: channel.name
                })
                .then(response => {
                    callback(false, response.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    callback(true, error);
                });
            }
        };
    }
});
```

In .env:

```
VITE_HOST='my-domain.com'
VITE_PORT=5173
VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
# VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="127.0.0.1"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

What am I wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: This is Soketi container logs:
`
Attaching to temp-staff_soketi_1
soketi_1        | 
soketi_1        |   ️‍♂️ Initiating metrics endpoints...  
soketi_1        | 
soketi_1        |     Server is up and running!   
soketi_1        |     The Websockets server is available at 127.0.0.1:6001   
soketi_1        |     The HTTP API server is available at http://127.0.0.1:6001   
soketi_1        |     The /usage endpoint is available on port 9601.   
soketi_1 
`

Comment: I sovled by forward to other port.